# How to create an interface from a class

Tags: java, android, interface, gesturedetector

I am new to Android Programming/ Java I wanted to know how I should add gesture Directions when I already have a `class` extended to MainActvity?

```
    package #####app.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener{

    private GestureDetectorCompat mygesture;
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    }



       @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
            }
        @Override
        public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

        }


        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            this.mygesture.onTouchEvent(event);
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Welcome to ####";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();

            WebView vedant = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.vedant);
            vedant.loadUrl("http://##.ml");
            WebSettings webSettings = vedant.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            vedant.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            this.mygesture = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
            mygesture.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);



        }
    }
```

I know that to use Gesture Direction I need to :

```
@Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
        float velocityY) {
            try {
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH){
                    return false;
                }
                // right to left swipe
                if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    onLeftSwipe();
                }
                // left to right swipe
                else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    onRightSwipe();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But for which I need to extend another class `SimpleOnGestureListener`.
As i could not extend to the `SimpleOnGestureListener` class I thought i could create a `interface` and then implement it. Is that possible. If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a `GestureDetectorCompat` with 2 parameters:

- The Context
- a listener (`GestureDetector.OnGestureListener`)

At the moment you do `mygesture = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);` where `this` is your Activity. But why do you want your Activity to be the listener? You can create a listener in a separated class.

So you can do:

**MainActivity**

```
this.mygesture = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener());
```

**MyGestureListener**

```
public class MyGestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
       // ... 
       // Your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it's a class. But your own class where you'll add features to the original SimpleOnGestureListener. And then you can use this new class as listener in the GestureDetector. You can name your class whatever you want, but yes you need to create a new Java file.

Comment: Worked like a charm, just wanted to know that why use () , when it is a class? we use it for function only rihgt??

Comment: Because you're creating a new instance of the class. Let's say you have a class A like that: public class A { public A(){ // default constructor of A}  public A(int i) { // some code}}. Now you can either instantiate the class like that A a = new A(); or like that A b = new A(42);